# After upgrade to 15.04, wrong temperature readings cause fan to go crazy

Tags: upgrade, suspend, fan, temperature

Since I upgraded to 15.04, twice after I had started it from suspended state Ubuntu would right away start spinning the laptop fan like crazy since it thought that one of the temperatures was 100°C (as the `sensors` command indicated). The particular temperature is usually around 30-40°C.

This happened only when I woke Ubuntu up from suspended state, and only twice so far, even though I've woken it up numerous times since the upgrade.

The problem doesn't go away until I restart Ubuntu.

Thoughts?

**EDIT:** Now this seems to happen whenever Ubuntu wakes from suspension.

Comment: sounds like a bug - probably better to report it to launchpad http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: I reported it, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I have HP 6910p and facing similar problem. It was temporarily solved with booting from old 3.16.0-34-generic kernel (via Grub Customizer).

Comment: After installation of 15.10 the issue remains .
Therefore I implement solution on found on fedora bug : 895276 comment 11.

Comment: All I have to change was to put script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep